# Updating an entry in a MongoDB collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

I cannot figure how to update an entry in my MongoDB collection. I have looked at the C# driver [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/#update-method), and I think I have followed them pretty closely.

However, one (or maybe both?) of the arguments that I am passing to the Update method is invalid. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using MongoDB.Bson;
using MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Attributes;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using MongoDB.Driver.Linq;


namespace Csharp_Linq
{
    class Program
    {
        public class Book
        {
            // Fields
            public string title { get; set; }
            public string author { get; set; }
            public ObjectId id { get; set; }

            // Constructors
            public Book()
            {
                this.title = "some title";
                this.author = "some author";
            }

            public Book(string title, string author)
            {
                this.title = title;
                this.author = author;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Connect to the server
            string connectionString = "mongodb://localhost";
            MongoClient client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
            MongoServer server = client.GetServer();

            // Get the database then the collection
            MongoDatabase database = server.GetDatabase("tutorial");
            MongoCollection collection = database.GetCollection("books");

            // Query the collection
            int count =
                (from book in collection.AsQueryable<Book>()
                 select book)
                .Count();

            string numBooks = String.Format("This collection has {0} books.", count);
            Console.WriteLine(numBooks);

            var query =
                from book in collection.AsQueryable<Book>()
                where book.author == "Ernest Hemingway"
                select book;

            foreach (var book in query)
            {
                string bookInfo = String.Format("{0} by {1}", book.title, book.author);
                Console.WriteLine(bookInfo);
            }

            // Insert new books
            Book scaryBook = new Book("Dr. Sleep", "Stephen King");
            Book[] batch = 
            {
                new Book(),
                scaryBook
            };
            collection.InsertBatch(batch);

            // Update default book
            var query2 =
                from book in collection.AsQueryable<Book>()
                where book.title == "some title" && book.author == "some author"
                select book;

            var update = new UpdateDocument {
                { "$set", new BsonDocument("title", "War and Peace") }
            };
            BsonDocument updatedBook = collection.Update(query2, update);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I am a little surprised that the Update method actually returns a BsonDocument.  Why does it do that?

Earlier I tried to use the Update object as shown in the example:

```
MongoCollection<BsonDocument> books;
var query = Query.And(
    Query.EQ("author", "Kurt Vonnegut"),
    Query.EQ("title", "Cats Craddle")
);
var update = Update.Set("title", "Cat's Cradle");
BsonDocument updatedBook = books.Update(query, update);
```

Does this object still exist?  Whenever I type it into Visual Studio, I get an error saying the object is not in the namespace.

Answer (score 2):

First I had to include

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
```

Then I had to cast my Linq query to a Mongo query.  Here is the resulting code:

```
        // Update default book
        var query2 =
            from book in collection.AsQueryable<Book>()
            where book.title == "some title" && book.author == "some author"
            select book;
        // Cast linq query to Mongo query
        var mongoQuery = ((MongoQueryable<Book>)query2).GetMongoQuery();

        var update = new UpdateDocument {
            { "$set", new BsonDocument("title", "War and Peace") }
        };
        collection.Update(mongoQuery, update);
```

Took a little research to get all of the pieces to fit!

Comment: Castin linq query into Mongo helps me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Update object is part of the MongoDB.Driver.Builders namespace, though this is not obvious from the tutorial.

Think the issue is with your query.  Unless you have a book with

```
 book.title == "some title" && book.author == "some author"
```

you're not going to find anything to update.

You're second example will work (once) if you add this to your code file.

```
using MongoDB.Driver.Builders;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update entry by following. Take case of item add to cart

```
db.carts.update({
_id: "the_users_session_id", status:'active'
}, {
 $set: { modified_on: ISODate() },
 $push: {
   products: {
     sku: "111445GB3", quantity: 1, title: "Simsong One mobile phone", price:1000
   }
 }
});
```

Please refer following for more info http://advancedmongodb.blogspot.in/